# Criando ng-model dinâmico com angular

Tags: angularjs, modelagem

Estou precisando criar o nome de uma model dinâmicamente, porem na hora de criar o obj o angular não aceita que eu tente criar o nome do obj dinamicamente. Alguém já fez isso ou sabe como proceder?

> O problema esta ocorrendo na data-ng-model, queria criar um objeto com o nome form com todos os seus atributos dinamicamente.

Segue abaixo o exemplo do HTML

```
<div data-ng-repeat="campos in lista">
      <div data-ng-switch="campo.type">
          <div data-ng-switch-when="text">
               <label data-ng-if="campo.label">{{campo.label}}</label>
               <input type="text" name="{{campo.name}}" placeholder="{{campo.placeholder}}" data-ng-model="form.{{campo.name}}" />
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar `form.{{campo.name}}`, utilize `form[campo.name]`.

De resto, não vejo problemas.

Comment: No caso ele vai criar um vetor e não um objeto correto?

Comment: Você esta correto e errado. Simplificadamente, um objeto, em Javascript, é um vetor (um map, se for metódico) de atributos. Ou seja, estruturalmente, um vetor e um objeto são muito semelhantes. Tanto que não existe um `typeof arr === "array"` e deve-se utilizar o método `Array.isArray`. Este artigo pode te ajudar a entender um pouco mais (em inglês) http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Comment: Enfim, não havia pensado dessa maneira. Obrigado.

Comment: Resolve meu problema dessa forma.